# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating an android app in visual studio 2015. While building the solution I am getting this error :

The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have update my visual studio as well. but nothing is working for me.

Here is snapshot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run visual studio as administrator or repair your visual studio from programs

see this post:
[Visual Studio 2012 csc.exe Error. Executable not valid for OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297704/visual-studio-2012-csc-exe-error-executable-not-valid-for-os)

Comment: have you tried to use a windows restore point? maybe you have a recent point

Comment: got it working after restoring Visual studio. may be some file was corrupted

Comment: great, i read in the link i sent you that some times the csc.exe corrupts and you must repair it copying someone else functional csc.exe file or repairing your visual studio