# Getting error while creating a new web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error while creating a new web application in VS2015.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error
>
> The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run. This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 csc.exe Error. Executable not valid for OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297704/visual-studio-2012-csc-exe-error-executable-not-valid-for-os)

Comment: There's a problem with csc.exe, or your admin actually blocked that executable.